# Laravel - Translate MySQL CONCAT string with date in Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-localization

I know I can translate in Laravel using the __ helper function, eg - in my blade template:

```
{{ __("Hello") }}
```

But what happens when I want to mix in variables to that? For example, imagine in my controller I am using MySQL to return a concat string as a variable which I want to output in my blade:

*Controller*

```
SELECT CONCAT("Commences ", commencement_date) AS calculated_current_year ...
```

*Template*

```
{{ __($collection->calculated_current_year) }}
```

If I have the necessary translation setup (in this case, Portuguese: `"Commences": "Início",` in the translation file, my expected result/output would be:

Início 2022-09-06

but instead I get

Commences 2022-09-06

How can I translate the partial match?

Comment: You can use carbon translation for translate *date*

Comment: in which file your translation is? like there should be a file mile messages.php

Comment: To clarify, my translations are in ```/resources/lange/pt.json``` and work fine in all other instances. If I only try to translate the word "Commences" it works, but the moment that becomes "Commences " (trailing space) or "Commences 2022-09-26" (or whatever date) - it doesnt work. Need it to work with the date.

Comment: /lang/ ^typo above